# Typescript: rename string literal type in VScode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

Given some string literal type:

```
declare type Test = "hello" | "world";

const test: Test = "hello";
```

I want to rename "hello", and I want the change will take effect also in the usage, but VScode doesn't let me to rename "hello" and just give me an error: `you cannot rename this element`.

Is there any tool or extension that will allow me to do this kind of refactor?
I know I can use enum, but I want a solution for string literal types specifically.

**UPDATE** I'v also found this open issue in typescript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5602

**UPDATE2**: I'v found out that **Intellij** supports doing exactly this- when you rename a string literal type, it will rename all the usages as well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'rename hello'? You mean you want to change 'hello' to another string when you are declaring type Test? Also why are you using the declare keyword, is the `Test` type from a non-Typescript file?

Comment: yes, I want to change hello to something else, and I want the change to take effect also in the usage, so after the change we will see: "const test:Test = "somethingElse".
about the declare keyword, this is an artificial example, in my real project the type is separated.

Comment: I think, "hello" as subtype of `string` is treated as a [predefined type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#381-predefined-types) similar to `string`, `number` etc. and not as user-defined type. As you only can rename user-defined types, that's unfortunately not possible, other than e.g. Ctrl+Shift+H replace.

Comment: Furthermore keep in mind that by replacing the literal in its declaration TypeScript will automatically complain in places where you're still referencing the old value. Just fix those occurrences, that is the reason of using TS over JS in the first place. :)

Comment: Where did you find that it's possible on IntelliJ ? I tried and searched for this feature but I can't find it

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel just try to rename the string literal (shirt+F6) and make sure the checkbox for searching text occurrences is off(!). you don't want to replace random text occurrences.

Comment: It works now ! I was probably tired, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTRL+F2 after selecting the string literal to be renamed. This will rename all occurrences of that string in the current file, including -warning here- variables. It is basically a shortcut for find/replace all in current file.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to say, because I always wanted to do that in my code, but sadly at the time of writing there's no tools or configuration to achieve what you wanted.

So, what I usually do is that I will open the global search and use the replace tool which can be opened using keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+f` or `Cmd+Shift+f`.